# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 246.00 MiB (GPU 0; 31.75 GiB total capacity; 9.51 GiB already allocated; 116.12 MiB free;

Tags: python

this is my code, my batch size is 16 and it is important for my code, so i couldn't change it ,what should i do to solve this problem.

this is linux and couldn't use the 'nvida -smi'.
This is a Linux server, and I don't have administrator rights to upgrade CUDA
I am a beginner of deep learning, and I found that many methods are not suitable for me after consulting the available materials.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models
import pickle
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchlibrosa.augmentation import SpecAugmentation
import pickle
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
import resnet_model
import sub_attention
from torch.autograd import Function, Variable

class AudioNet_v2_pooling(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,dim):
        super(AudioNet_v2_pooling, self).__init__()
        sub_attention.init_gobal_variable(a=512, b=512, c=64, d=8)
        self.encoder1 = sub_attention.Encoder(1)
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=(1, 7), stride=(3, 4), padding=(0,0)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2,1)
        )

        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 5), stride=(3, 3), padding=(0,0)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, 1)
        )

        self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 5), stride=(1, 3), padding=(0,0)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU())

        self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, dim, kernel_size=(1, 5), stride=(1, 3), padding=(0,0)),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(dim),
            nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, x):
        # print(x.size())
        # [3, 96, 512]
        x = self.encoder1(x)
        # [3, 96, 512]
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        # [3, 1, 96, 512]
        x = self.conv1(x)
        # [3, 64, 32, 170]
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = torch.mean(x,dim=-1).transpose(1,2)
        return x
class VideoNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,dim=1024):
        super(VideoNet, self).__init__()
        self.dim = dim
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Linear(2048,dim),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.BatchNorm1d(dim)
                )
        self.resnet = resnet_model.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        self.maxpool = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((1, 1))
    def forward(self,x):
        batch = x.size(0)
        x = self.resnet(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)+self.maxpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = x.view(int(batch / 10), 10, self.dim)
        return x

class Encoder1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder1, self).__init__()
        self.encoder1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(10, 90, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(90),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2,inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(90, 180, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(180),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        )
        self.en_fc11=nn.Linear(180*256,8)
        self.en_fc12=nn.Linear(180*256,8)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.encoder1(x)  # auido2: torch.Size([3, 180, 256])
        mean1 = self.en_fc11(x.view(x.shape[0], -1))
        logstd1 = self.en_fc12(x.view(x.shape[0], -1))
        eps1 = torch.randn(mean1.shape).cuda()
        z1 = mean1.cuda() + eps1 * torch.exp(logstd1).cuda()
        return z1

class Encoder2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder2, self).__init__()
        self.encoder2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(10, 90, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(90),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv1d(90, 180, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(180),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        )
        self.en_fc21 = nn.Linear(180 * 256, 8)
        self.en_fc22 = nn.Linear(180 * 256, 8)

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.encoder2(x) #img3: torch.Size([3, 180, 256])
        mean2 = self.en_fc21(x.view(x.shape[0], -1)) #mean2: torch.Size([3, 8])
        logstd2 = self.en_fc22(x.view(x.shape[0], -1))
        eps2 = torch.randn(mean2.shape).cuda()
        z2 = mean2.cuda() + eps2 * torch.exp(logstd2).cuda()
        return z2


class Decoder1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder1, self).__init__()
        self.de_fc1 = nn.Linear(8, 180 * 256)
        self.decoder1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(180, 256, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(256, 256, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(256, 10, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )
        self.decoder_fc_13 = nn.Linear(2048, 1024)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.de_fc1(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0],180,256)
        out1 = self.decoder1(x)
        out1 = self.decoder_fc_13(out1)
        out1 = out1.view(out1.shape[0],-1,10)
        out1 = out1.permute(0, 2, 1)
        return out1



class Decoder2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder2, self).__init__()
        self.de_fc2 = nn.Linear(8, 180 * 256)
        self.decoder2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(180, 256, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(256, 256, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(256, 10, 4, 2, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )
        self.decoder_fc_23 = nn.Linear(2048, 1024)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.de_fc2(x) #imgd1: torch.Size([3, 46080])
        x= x.view(x.shape[0],180,256)
        out2 = self.decoder2(x) #imgd2: torch.Size([3, 10, 2048])
        out2 = self.decoder_fc_23(out2) #imgd3: torch.Size([3, 10, 1024])
        out2 = out2.view(out2.shape[0],-1,10)
        out2 = out2.permute(0, 2, 1)
        return out2

class Mixed_model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,dim=1024):
        super(Mixed_model, self).__init__()
        self.audio_net = AudioNet_v2_pooling(dim=1024)
        self.video = VideoNet(dim=dim)
        self.encoder1 = Encoder1()
        self.encoder2 = Encoder2()
        self.decoder1 = Decoder1()
        self.decoder2 = Decoder2()
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim*2 , dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(dim , 10)
        )


    def forward(self,img,audio):
        batch = img.size(0)
        audio = self.audio_net(audio) #auido1: torch.Size([3, 10, 1024])
        z1 = self.encoder1(audio)
        img = img.view(batch*10,3,224,224)
        img = self.video(img) #torch.Size([3, 10, 1024]) torch.Size([16, 10, 1024]
        z2 = self.encoder2(img)
        audio = self.decoder1(z2)
        img =self.decoder2(z1)
        mixed = torch.cat([audio,img],dim=-1) #mixed: torch.Size([3, 10, 2048])
        result = self.classifier(mixed) #mixed: torch.Size([3, 10, 10])
        result = torch.mean(result,dim=1)+torch.max(result,dim=1)[0]
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':



    model = Mixed_model(1024)
    x = torch.rand(3,10, 3, 224, 224)
    y = torch.rand(3,96,512)
    img = model(x,y)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXDuS.png)

Comment: Don't know anything about torch, but the error is clear. You don't have enough free memory to run your code. No real way around that. Lowering the batch size could help, but like you said that's not an option. Is this the only program running on that machine? Maybe cull some other processes?

Comment: Ok, I can try to contact the server administrator and have him restart the server to free up some memory.Thank you for your answer